# Non-nullable DateTime (in)equality with null compiles and runs?

Tags: .net, datetime, compilation

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58162901/463623), I (and OP in said question) got confused, when this piece of code compiles and runs :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
bool isFalse = dateTime == null;
bool isTrue  = dateTime != null;
```

Notice that the `dateTime` variable is not `nullable`. When I hover over the equality sign, it tells me it is's signature is bool `DateTime.operator==(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2)` and the `null` is of `Nullable<DateTime>`.

What is compiler doing here? Is it using some kind of implicit conversion?

I have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588113/why-is-there-no-compiler-error-when-i-test-for-a-datetime-null-and-a-compiler-er), but it just shrugs away the problem and doesn't explain why compiler is doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rules for [Binary operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution):

> An operation of the form `x op y`, where `op` is an overloadable binary operator, `x` is an expression of type `X`, and `y` is an expression of type `Y`, is processed as follows:
>
> - The set of candidate user-defined operators provided by `X` and `Y` for the operation `operator op(x,y)` is determined. The set consists of the union of the candidate operators provided by `X` and the candidate operators provided by `Y`, each determined using the rules of Candidate user-defined operators. [...]

[Candidate user-defined operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#candidate-user-defined-operators%5D) says:

> For all `operator op` declarations in `T0` **and all lifted forms of such operators**, if at least one operator is applicable with respect to the argument list `A`, then the set of candidate operators consists of all such applicable operators in `T0`.

[Lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators):

> ***Lifted operators*** permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - For the equality operators `==  !=`
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

So the compiler looks at the operands `DateTime` and `null`, finds the user-defined [`==(DateTime, DateTime)` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_equality), and lifts it to `==(DateTime?, DateTime?)`. As both `DateTime` and `null` can be implicitly converted to `DateTime?`, this lifted operator is applicable and ultimately selected as the best candidate.